# Tkinter font not changing

Tags: python, tkinter, fonts

Please help me, why the font of my text doesn't change?

```
from tkinter import *

fenetre=Tk()
fenetre.focus_force()
fenetre.title("Puissance 4")
fenetre.geometry('900x925')
c=Canvas(fenetre,width=900,height=925,bg="royalblue")
c.place(x=0,y=0)
c.create_text(450,75, anchor='center', font=('Arial',50), text="Au tour du Joueur 2",fill='Black')
c.create_text(450,175, anchor='center', font=('Time',50), text="Au tour du Joueur 2",fill='Black')

fenetre.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3):

Probably just a typo. If I change "Time" to "Times", it works just fine on my computer.

[image: 1]

Answer (score 2):

Your code is fine. Just that tkinter doesn't support 'Time'. Please, go to [List available font families in `tkinter`](https://www.py4u.net/discuss/142598) for tkinter font list.